# Magix web designer Premium

Tags: wine

I've used Magix Web Designer Premium software for years and really like how easy the program is to use but I'm in the process of trying to switch completely to Ubuntu (not a dual boot system; strictly Ubuntu) and although I've got Wine installed I can't get the Magix software to install.  Has anyone out there already done this? I really want to keep using Magix.  I'm still extremely new to this (have only started using Ubuntu a month ago) and am wondering if I am doing it right. I also tried installing a Windows dice game using Wine but that didn't work either.

Comment: Visit https://appdb.winehq.org/index.php and click e.g. "Browse by Developer" or "Browse Apps" in the left sidebar to search for your application and find out how well it is supported by Wine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no database entry for Magix in the appdb, so we can assume that nobody else tried.

Launching the program from the terminal and pasting its output would be helpful for analysis. You should [report a bug to the Wine developers](https://bugs.winehq.org/) using the [latest version](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

I understand that this program has a workflow which is nice and easy for you, but if you browse around some sites on the web focused on web design you will realize that designers mostly work with text editors, web browser developer tools and documentation (HTML, DOM, CSS, JS, etc). Here is an example of such a [site](https://css-tricks.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I know there are other web design programs that work with Linux; our website: Robert Rocks The Mandolin has a Magix web address  since we got free webspace with the software.  The change of web address is a bigger issue than the software itself. That's why I'd like to keep using Magix if possible.  I was able to install some of my other Windows programs using Wine but Magix gets stuck after 3/4 installation.  I'm not sure if it's the software itself that's causing the problem or the fact that it requires a lot of memory and our current computer is 12 years old.